# How to set up Apache Kafka Broker on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have installed Apache Kafka on my EC2 instance, changed the security groups to open ports 9092 and 2181 for Kafka and Zookeeper. I only have a single broker, single topic, single partition nothing complex. I confirmed Kafka works by trying local producers/consumers.

On AWS security groups it shows:

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
2181
0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
9092
0.0.0.0/0

Now I want to connect my producers and consumers (not on a Amazon EC2 instance) using the public IP of my Broker EC2 instance. However I cannot connect any of my producers or consumers to the EC2 Broker. They just say Broker not found.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check whether you can reach (SSH for example) your EC2 instance first from outside VPC? (You'll need to open port 22 to SSH).

Comment: Trying to connect to the system externally is indeed the first thing to do. You can easily try connecting directly to the ports (as they are TCP) using:

`telnet <public name> 2181`
`telnet <public name> 9092`

If there is no rejection and you can input text, then there is no networking issue. If not , you would get a better clue of what is blocking the communication.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that Kafka by default advertises the broker names in Zookeeper. On AWS, it usually uses internal EC2 DNS names that cannot be resolved externally. Take a look at the `advertised.listeners` property of the [broker config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#configuration)